# correct use of mvc principle between a view controller to a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uitabbarcontroller

I'm building a todo app, and I want to create a "History" page in the app.

Right now I have a model file and I created in it a "todo" entity with some different attributes (body, status , time etc), and im using core data to holds those todo's.

So I created a button to the "History" page which is a table view, and Now im trying to figure out how to keep the todo's that was marked done and populate the History page (table view) cells with this todo's.

So I thought that in the Home view controller I will create an NSMutableArray property called "todos", And ill create a method in the Home view controller .m file that is adding todos to the todos property, import the home view controller to the history table view controller and populate it's cells with the todos array property.

How bad is this solution?

thanks

Comment: Why not just use NSPredicate to fetch "done" todo objects from CoreData?

Comment: @Peter Zhou - what is the point in having a model if the controller is accessing CoreData directly?

Comment: Why are you bothering with the home controller passing todos onto the history controller? - Just have the history controller fetch the todos directly from the model, when they are updated in the history controller send the updated ones back to the model for the model to save the changes.

Comment: @Gruntcakes can you demonstrate the code for this solution? im kind of new to core data so it will help

Comment: I thought from your question you were already using core data? Anyway your question is not about core data but about mvc design, if you need to ask about core data that is another question, but it may be too heavyweight for this. Anyway the point of using a model is abstraction - your VC(s) would ask the model for a list of todos (probably in the form of an NSArray). Your VCs have no idea the model is using core data to store the todos, that is the whole point of designing like this using a model.

Comment: If the VC(s) get the todos from the model then the VC(s) have no exposure to core data, and if the model implementation changes from using core data to using something else then the VC code does not have to change. That is the whole point about using design patters. Your question is about design, asking for code snippets about core data is about how the model might implement the storage - these are two different things and two different questions.

Comment: Core data is complex and heavyweight. For now I would just have your model store your todos as an array in NSUserDefaults. That will be very very quick and easy to implement. Later if its necessary you could change that implementation from NSUserDefaults to core data.

Comment: @Gruntcakes ok cool thanks for the solution with NSUserDefaults, i think i will use it. Just curious, is my solution not working? just having an array property in the home view controller and get access to it from the history table view controller. or this is just not right sw designing wise?

Comment: It depends on the relationship and use of your two view controllers. It introduces a relationship from your HTVC to your HVC which may not otherwise need to exist.If the only reason for that relationship is for the HTVC to get the todos then it is an unnecessary relationship. Design is all about simplifying things and removing unnecessary relationships. in the other design you would however introduce a relationship between the HTVC and the Model so its all about playoffs. In your design how did you plan on the HTVC knowing about the existence of HVC in order that it can get the todos from it?

Comment: If i will add the todos property to my hvc .h and impot hvc .h to htvc cant i access its data from the htvc? @Gruntcakes

Comment: No, that's just a file containing a class. *A class is not the same thing as an object. A class doesn't store data an object does*. If you import that file then your htvc *class* will know what the definition of the hvc *class* is, but on its own that is no use. An *object* of the class type of hvc needs to be created, then an *object* of the class type of htvc needs to get access to that htvc object. How would your htvc *object* get access to the hvc *object*? These objects needs to be created somewhere in your program, where and how will they be created.

Comment: >> "where and how will they be created." You might yourself not need to create these as they may be created automatically for you if you are using a storyboard. But you need need to consider how an object of htvc will be able to access an object of hvc. Have I confused you?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using an array to hold your todos. This could potentially result in excessive memory use and performance degradation. To display Core Data entities in a table view, use the `NSFetchedResultsController` class which was specifically designed for this purpose.

You can find boilerplate code from the Xcode template (choose Master-Detail, check "Core Data" and look at the master view controller).

In your lazy initiator of the fetched results controller, add this predicate:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"done = YES"];
```

or instead of `done` use whatever flag you have included in your model to indicate that an item should be shown in the history view.